# Speed up SELECT from several tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I need to speed up an sql query. Or handle the php code better. Some best practice when searching a database and displaying the result in the frontend.

Basically I have three tables
 - boxes, that contains records
 - records, that contains songs
 - song

I would like my frontend code to list something like:

```
Box 1
 -Record 1
  --Song 1
  --Song 2
    etc....
 -Record 2
  --Song 1
  --Song 2
    etc....
Box 2
 -Record 1
  --Song 1
  --Song 1
etc. etc. etc.
```

"My way" is very time consuming:

1. I search the "Box" table using standard SQL.
2. For each row I call a function that finds each record for that box
3. For each record I call a function that finds each song for that record

It takes a loooong time to complete since the number of select calls is enormous (many boxes, many recors)

I guess there is a more easy way (from the servers pointy of view) to do the same. Pull dato to php arrays and to the logic there or something else that is clever.

**Question:**
What is the best practice to get data from a relational database using php?

Br. Anders

Comment: Hammerite is right. You should use joins, this way you have to run only a single query which will be a lot faster than your current approach. Also, you can use primary and foreign keys or indexed columns for your join path to further increase the speed of your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn about `JOIN`s. Here, you would use two outer joins. That way, you achieve the same result using only one select query, and the amount of work that has to be done by PHP and by MySQL is much less.

Your SQL would look something like this: (Note that I use `SELECT *` as a stand-in for the real list of columns, because I don't know what columns you have - using `SELECT *` is generally not a good idea)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Box
    LEFT JOIN Record ON Box.BoxID = Record.BoxID
    LEFT JOIN Song ON Record.RecordID = Song.RecordID
```

Comment: +1 for the left joins, allowing selection of boxes with no records :)

Comment: Thanks. But I do not know how to get from an sql statement with a join to display the data on the website. So maybe it is more a php question than an sql question

Comment: You just need to use a loop, the way you have already been doing. Perhaps use variables to track when you have moved to the next record/the next box, since then you may want to reflect that in the displayed data.

Comment: Yep. Suddenly it makes sence. I can pull date with joins and save it in an array in php. Then run through the array to create the output. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A single set based select operation will be quicker than many single row based selects.

you achieve this using joins
see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

I have no idea of you database structure, so this will not be a working example, 
here is how to return all of the songs for a particular box.

```
SELECT s.* FROM box b
INNER JOIN record r ON r.box_id = b.box_id
INNER JOIN song s ON s.record_id = r.record_id
WHERE box.name = 'mybox'
```

will be quicker than:

```
select from box b
   where box.name = 'mybox'
LOOP
  select record_id from record 
  LOOP
      select * from song
  END 
END
```

Comment: You should use a "left join" instead of "inner join" which will then allow the selection of boxes without records. The above will only pull boxes that contain records. See @Hammerite's answer for an example.

Comment: if there were no records in box "mybox", then yours would return zero rows, using a "left join" would return a single row containing the fact that the box "mybox" does in fact exist, even though it has no records in it.

Comment: Fair enough ;) I'd still be interested to know which boxes didn't have any records in though. I've had instances before where I needed to show all the items in the first table, even if there aren't any in the subsequent joined tables. Yes, I think it would be more a UI issue, possibly like in a contacts list, where you may not have any contacts under "Q" for instance, but still want to show the header... :)